# Weird floating issue in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c

```
float abc = 145606035;
NSLog(@"%f", abc);
NSLog(@"%d", abc);


First NSLog = 145606032.000000 //this is wrong, please look at the last digit.
Second NSLog = 536870912 //this is wrong too!
```

Why the answer so weird? Does it make sense? The 'abc' not even exceed the Integer maximum number, how come the number is wrong? Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is because it interprets the binary representation of abc as an integer. Decimal numbers and integers in binary representation are completely different and to get the correct output you should cast abc to an int `(int)abc`

The first output is off because of the precision of floating point numbers. A float has to break it's precision into the whole part of the number as well as sign and trailing decimals. This means that the range for floating point numbers is limited especially using 32 bit floats. With double type you should get the correct output for the first number.

Comment: Thank! Then how about the first output? why the last digit is not correct?

Comment: Thank again! I thought float can support even longer number ? When I look at this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd7199ke(v=vs.80).aspx it says it can support up to 3.402823466 E + 38. Do I interpret it wrongly?

Comment: @GMsoF http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html
This explains a little more and you'll see why that value won't "fit" into a float. Double's should fix your issues but precision is always a problem with computers. If you require near infinite precision try to find a BigNum library for your chosen implementation language.

Answer (score 0):

It will always give you this type of answer. Look at your code, in the first line you are assigning float value to the variable "ABC", then in the first NSLOG you are asking to give you float value (this one is right). In the second NSLOG you are asking to give you integer value (this one is not right).

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Try assigning something like this **142.43** it will give you the exact float value;

Comment: Yes, it could be, but my app need to store something longer than 142.43